# vue-recaptcha-v3 and Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, recaptcha-v3

Does anyone implement vue-recaptcha in vue 3? Please share with.

I want to create "I am not a robot" in my project, but there are some problem with vue 3.

Part of errors are :

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                   10:26:28 AM

error  in ./src/components/SignUp.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js

Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected "," (58:39)

56 |         };
57 |

> 58 |         const handleSuccess = (response: string) => {
> |                                        ^
> 59 |             // Do some validation
> 60 |         };
> 61 |

ERROR in ./src/components/SignUp.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/components/SignUp.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /home/mahjube/Documents/Templetes/customer-ui/src/components/SignUp.vue: Unexpected token, expected "," (58:39)

56 |         };
57 |

> 58 |         const handleSuccess = (response: string) => {
> |                                        ^
> 59 |             // Do some validation
> 60 |         };
> 61 |
> at instantiate (/home/mahjube/Documents/Templetes/customer-ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:653:32)
> at constructor (/home/mahjube/Documents/Templetes/customer-ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:946:12)
> at JSXParserMixin.raise (/home/mahjube/Documents/Templetes/customer-ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3270:19)
> at JSXParserMixin.unexpected (/home/mahjube/Documents/Templetes/customer-ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3300:16)
> at JSXParserMixin.expect (/home/mahjube/Documents/Templetes/customer-ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:3642:28)
> at JSXParserMixin.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/home/mahjube/Documents/Templetes/customer-ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11476:14)
> at JSXParserMixin.parseExprAtom (/home/mahjube/Documents/Templetes/customer-ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11141:23)
> at JSXParserMixin.parseExprAtom (/home/mahjube/Documents/Templetes/customer-ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:7007:20)
> at JSXParserMixin.parseExprSubscripts (/home/mahjube/Documents/Templetes/customer-ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10872:23)
> at JSXParserMixin.parseUpdate (/home/mahjube/Documents/Templetes/customer-ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10855:21)
> at JSXParserMixin.parseMaybeUnary (/home/mahjube/Documents/Templetes/customer-ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10831:23)
> at JSXParserMixin.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (/home/mahjube/Documents/Templetes/customer-ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10669:61)
> at JSXParserMixin.parseExprOps (/home/mahjube/Documents/Templetes/customer-ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10674:23)
> at JSXParserMixin.parseMaybeConditional (/home/mahjube/Documents/Templetes/customer-ui/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10651:23)